# Cannot add multiple HTML code snippets to wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress, code-snippets

I have a HTML code with a canvas and a button, and all the necessary drawings are inside the draw(canvas) function.

```
    <script>
        init = (event) => {
        canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")
        draw(canvas);
        }
    
        window.onload = init
    </script>

    <canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas><br>
    <button type="button">Button</button>
```

I am trying to include this code in a WordPress post, and I have managed to do so (with both the 'WPCode' and 'Insert HTML Snippet' plugins). As long as I only have one figure it works fine, but when I try to add the figure one more time later in the post, it stops working. I should have two buttons and two figures, but instead it is two buttons and just one canvas.

It seems like the two code snippets interfere with each other. If I remove the first one, the second one works just fine. How can I include two identical figures so that they don't interfere?

I have tried inserting two independent HTML code snippets in two different WordPress blocks, expecting them to function independently.

Answer (score 0):

If you place the same code twice you are calling the same function at different points and still only referencing the first canvas block while having two blocks with the same `id`. Set the second block to have the `id` of `canvas2` or similar as below.

Add the canvas block where you first inserted it:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="400"></canvas><br>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Add the canvas2 later in the article:

```
<canvas id="canvas2" width="500" height="400"></canvas><br>
<button type="button">Button</button>
```

Add the new script at the very end of the article in another code snippet block:

```
<script>
    init = (event) => {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    draw(canvas);
    canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
    draw(canvas2);
    }
    window.onload = init;
</script>
```